# Having issues with python selenium and getting text out of the webelement

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, text

I am having an issue with python selenium and getting text out of a webelement. I am running python 3.6.8 and selenium 3.141.0.

I am finding a webelement using the xpath and loading it into a test variable (testvar). That test variable is a list of only one index (testvar[0]). I am basically trying to get the text string ('0.000') out of the webelement and into a testtext variable.

Shown below is the current variable output, code, and debug screens. As you can see the testtext variable is blank but the testvar[0] text has '0.000' in it.

I have tried:
testtext=testvar[0].text()
but this comes back with an error of "'str' object is not callable"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but if someone can point out what I am doing wrong, It would be very helpful.

[Code, variables, and debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdmeY.png)

EDIT:
Just for more information, if I change code on line 67 from .text to .tag_name, the testtext variable gets 'uni-view' like I suspected.

FINAL EDIT - SOLUTION
The problem ended up being two issues. The first was I was using find_elements_by_xpath and that was giving me the list. The second issue was that I was not giving enough time between when I requested the webpage and when I started finding the element. I added a sleep 5 between the get request and the find_element_by_xpath. Once I did that testvar.text worked just fine.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your solution as an answer so people can easily find it in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION The problem ended up being two issues. The first was I was using find_elements_by_xpath and that was giving me the list. The second issue was that I was not giving enough time between when I requested the webpage and when I started finding the element. I added a sleep 5 between the get request and the find_element_by_xpath. Once I did that testvar.text worked just fine.